# Retrieving multiple users from Parse via REST API and using only one AFNetworking request

Tags: ios, parse-platform, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I need to retrieve multiple users from `Parse.com`, via their `REST API`, and using `AFNetworking`. I need to retrieve these users using one single API call.

The following code is able to fetch one user. You will notice that I am including one `objectId` because I am only fetching one user. I need to modify this code so that I can call for multiple `objectId's` and as a result, retrieve multiple users:

```
//Setup request manager
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:ApplicationId forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:APIKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *query = @{@"objectId":@"cbfG5dFJy7"};
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:query
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
NSString *dateQueryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"where": dateQueryString};

//Perform request
[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@users", BaseURLString] parameters:parameters
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         // Handle success
         completion(nil, self.mentors, nil);

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         // Handle failure
         completion(nil, nil, error);
     }];
```

In the `Parse.com REST API documentation`, it says that you can perform a `compound or query` to achieve this, and it lists the following in the GET request curl example:

```
--data-urlencode 'where={"$or":[{"wins":{"$gt":150}},{"wins":{"$lt":5}}]}' \
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to translate that into objective-c. Here is the same example only in python if that helps:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
       "$or": [
         {
           "wins": {
             "$gt": 150
           }
         },
         {
           "wins": {
             "$lt": 5
           }
         }
       ]
     })})
```

I just need to include multiple `objectId's` in my `AFNetworking` call, and tell `Parse.com` that I'll accept results for this `objectId`, or that `objectId`, etc. so that `Parse.com` will return all of those users to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have a single dictionary for your query that you convert to JSON

```
NSDictionary *query = @{@"objectId":@"cbfG5dFJy7"};
```

The or example you show is a dictionary with a single key, where the value is an array of dictionaries like your current query.

```
@{@"$or":@[ @{@"objectId":@""} , @{@"objectId":@""} ]}
```

Once you have built this structure you convert it to JSON and add it to the request as you currently are.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only thing that I would add, is that you need to add "@" before each dictionary inside of the array to make it true Objective-C that will compile.